# Difference between "System.Linq.Dynamic", "Dynamic Expression API" and "DynamicLINQ" on NuGet?

Tags: linq, dynamic, expression, nuget, nuget-package

I noticed that there are 3 versions with the same functionality available on NuGet ?

- System.Linq.Dynamic (Microsoft)
- Dynamic Expression API (Microsoft)
- DynamicLINQ (David Fowler)

Can someone explain the differences ? And which one is the best package to use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference is that Dynamic Expression API (DynamicQuery) supports .NET 3.5 and System.Linq.Dynamic also supports .NET 4.0

The DynamicLinq package has a totally different usage and API.